# The code goes before taking the data from the firebase // angular 2

Tags: multithreading, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to take data from firebase and its success but its take a few second,
the code continue, so the value of variable is null.
why it's happening? it's threaded? and what can i do?

gameslist.component.ts

```
        import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
        import {Game} from './Game'
        import {NgStyle} from "angular2/common";
        import {DataService} from "./data.service";

        declare var firebase: any;

        @Component({
            selector:'gameslist',
            templateUrl: 'app/ts/gameslist.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['app/ts/gameslist.component.css'],
            inputs: ['games'],
            directives: [NgStyle],
            providers:[DataService]

        })

        export class gamesListComponent{
            public games;
            public currentGame=[];
            public votes1: number;
        constructor(private dataService:DataService){ this.votes1=0;this.currentGame=[];}

            fbPostVote(id_game:number,ChooseVote:number){
                this.votes1=this.dataService.getGameById(id_game);   //Here return null     
                this.votes1++;
                var updates = {};
                updates['/games/'+id_game+'/rec_1_votes'] = this.votes1;
                updates['/games/'+id_game+'/rec_1_color'] = 'pink';
                this.games[id_game].rec_1_color = 'pink';    
                return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
```

data.service.ts

```
       import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
        import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
         import 'rxjs/Rx'; 

         @Injectable()   
          export class DataService{

        constructor(private http:Http){        }         

        getGameById(id_game:number){
              firebase.database().ref('/games/'+id_game+'/rec_1_votes').on('value',function(snap) { 
               return snap.val();
                 });
             }
     }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`getGameById()` doesn't return anything. Change it to

```
    getGameById(id_game:number){
          return firebase.database().ref('/games/'+id_game+'/rec_1_votes').on('value',function(snap) { 
           return snap.val();
             });
         }
```

Comment: Yes you right, but its return the function, how dan i use it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Just add the additional `return` I added in my answer. The `return` in your original code only returns from the callback passed to `on(...)` but doesn't return from `getGameById()`

Comment: Yes i understand, but how can use it in 'gameslist.component.ts' code?

Comment: `this.getGameById.subscribe(data => { /* code that processes received data here like */ this.data = data });`

Comment: Not work, getGameById() return function(snap){return snap.val()}

Comment: And i can't use snap.val()